# How do I delay evaluation of a Spring @Conditional configuration annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

I have a Spring `@Configuration` class that should register a bean when a specific property value is set in the environment. I wrote a custom `Condition` implementation that checked whether the value was present, and it works when I fire up the application in Spring Boot, but the bean was never registered when running JUnit tests. I debugged the application and determined that the `Condition` was being evaluated before the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` was being instantiated.

I modified my `Condition` to implement `ConfigurationCondition` and specify evaluation during the `REGISTER_BEAN` phase. The method is still called before the configurer is instantiated, but the registered bean now comes and goes as I add or remove the property from the properties file.

Is this the best way to reorder the evaluation? Is this what the `ConfigurationCondition` interface is for, or am I just accidentally getting it to work now?

```
@Conditional(PropertyCondition.class)
@Configuration
public class PostbackUrlConfiguration {
    @Value("${serviceName.postbackUrl}")
    String postbackUrl;

    @Bean
    public PostbackUrlProvider provider() {
        return new FixedUrlProvider(postbackUrl);
    }
}
```

```
public class PropertyCondition implements ConfigurationCondition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return context.getEnvironment().containsProperty("serviceName.postbackUrl");
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase() {
        return ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN;
    }
}
```

The test configuration is a static class on my test case:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("classpath:/postback.properties")
@Import(PostbackUrlConfiguration.class)
public static class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a @ Configuration and @ Bean annotations to declare your PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in your JUnit Test?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeBond Yes, and the PSPC is `static` as per some requirement I saw for that kind of component specifically. Full test config class posted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [parsing phase](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationCondition.ConfigurationPhase.html#PARSE_CONFIGURATION) for a `@Configuration` class involves [reading its class definition, populating a collection of Configuration objects (because one `@Configuration` class may `@Import` another `@Configuration` class so these imports are parsed as well), processing `@PropertySources`, `@ImportResources` etc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3e4b3cad6ab632ae6af08f591194331d9669a1f3/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java#L270).

Processing `@PropertySources` doesn't, also, load those properties yet. After the parsing phase is done, the `@PropertySources` properties are loaded. After these are loaded, then the beans' definitions from inside `@Configuration` classes are registered (REGISTER_BEAN phase).

So, what you see using a `ConfigurationCondition` with `ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN` phase is expected because those properties are actually available in the `Environment` at the time when beans' definitions are registered and after the `@Configuration` class has been parsed.
Using just a `Condition` I believe it doesn't even reach the parsing phase of a `@Configuration`, the evaluation is done even before that, when the `@Configuration` class definition is to be registered.

Comment: I am trying to use this solution but my custom property sources are loaded only after the condition is evaluated. the only property sources that are loaded are "systemProperties" and "systemEnvironment"... is that normal?