# How to autowired profile configuration class on startup?

Tags: java, spring, datasource, autowired

I'd like to create different database profile classes, each for a purpose of development, production and testing.

I tried the following with the help of http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/, but it won't wire correctly. Why?

```
 interface DataConfig {
        DataSource dataSource();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("dev")
    public class StandaloneDataConfig implements DataConfig {
        @Bean
        @Override
        public dataSource dataSource() {
            //return the ds
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("prod")
    public class JndiDataConfig implements DataConfig { ... }

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource({"classpath:config.properties"})
    class AppConfig {
        @Autowired
        private DataConfig cfg;

    }

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@Import(AppConfig.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringBootConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

config.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Result: Exception on startup

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private DataConfig dataConfig; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [DataConfig] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE

My setup though seem to work in general: if I remove the @Profile annotation on one of the databases, everything wires up correctly.

Comment: I don't have any beans.xml as using annotation based config only.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?, If you are, could you please show the main configuration class (which I guess is AppConfig)?

Comment: yes I'm using spring boot, updated above. In general my setup is ok, bacause if I remove `@Profile` annotation on one of the databases, everything wires up correctly.

Comment: What happens if you rename your properties file to `application.properties`?

Comment: Oh great!! I created a `application.properties` file and placed the `spring.profiles.active=dev` there instead of in my custom config file. Works! (you might consider adding this as an answer so I can accept it)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! I added it an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename your `config.properties` file to `application.properties` for Spring Boot to pick it up automatically.

Comment: Now, a last question would be interesting: how can I tell spring to look for the application.properties outside of the classpath, so that in production I can create a local `application.properties` file somewhere that always overrides any existing settings with `spring.profiles.active=prod`?

Comment: That is a very good question. Check out section 21 from http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-documentation for the full details. Spring Boot provides lots of defaults for you to choose from

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your configuration, but my best guess (following some investigation I've done for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526643/how-do-i-delay-evaluation-of-a-spring-conditional-configuration-annotation)) is that `@PropertySources` are not available for a `@Conditional` annotated `@Configuration` class when autowiring occurs.

According to the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.java), `@Profile` is a `@Conditional` flavor of annotation with a [`Condition`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ProfileCondition.java) implementation.
For `@PropertySource` to be available when they are needed I think you would need your own custom `@Conditional` implementation just like in the SO post I mentioned above, where you define not a `Condition` but a `ConfigurationCondition` making sure to be used at `ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN` phase.